# Removing images in horizontalscroll view while click the checkbox in another listview

Tags: android

Here i try to remove the images added in the horizontal scroll view while click the check box from another list view check1 is the id of checkbox 
  inHorizontalScrollView is the id of horizontal scrollview and i add the imageview on addView() method.
Adding the view is not an issue when remove the view it removes only the last view
Thanks Alot...

```
      check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                //set your object's last status
                m.setSelected(isChecked);
                if (check1.isChecked()) {
                    list.add(m.getid());

                    li = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    view = li.inflate(R.layout.sample, null);
                    final ImageView i = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image5);
                    i.setId(Integer.parseInt(m.getid()));

                    viewList.add(view);
                    inHorizontalScrollView.addView(view);


                } else {
                    viewList.remove(view);
                    inHorizontalScrollView.removeView(view);
                    list.remove(m.getid());

                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view always store the last created view. You need to store all your inflated views somewhere and remove the concrete view from your layout.

Comment: thanks @grig for replying...need a sample program or reference can you explain little bit detail about this ...once again thank you..

Answer (score 0):

This is the code

```
    else {
                    //Remove user id from list
                    list.remove(m.getid());
                    //Remove image path from list
                    imagelist.remove(m.getThumbnailUrl());
                    //Remove all views from scrollview
                    inHorizontalScrollView.removeAllViews();
                    for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++)
                    {
                        li = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        view = li.inflate(R.layout.sample, null);
                        final ImageView i = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image5);

                        i.setId(Integer.parseInt(list.get(j)));

                        Glide.with(getContext()).load(imagelist.get(j)).asBitmap().placeholder(R.drawable.profileicon).centerCrop().into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(i) {
                            @Override
                            protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                                RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                                        RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(view.getContext().getResources(), resource);
                                circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
                                i.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
                            }
                        });
                        //add stored views from list and imagelist
                        inHorizontalScrollView.addView(view);
                    }
```